# How to play video in line without open up to full screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, ios10

This is my first message app. The tutorial i been watch only teach me how to play the video with full screen. It will be cool if i can play the video without open up to another window or full screen.
i been trying a lot of other stuff but still cant get it to work.
Also now when i playing the video it goes to full screen and the load bar is gonna too. (Xcode 8, iOS 10)

[image: screenshot]

How would modify my code for the video not playing in full screen?

Comment: Images of your code are totally useless to us. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the reasons why. Code is text, and you can copy and paste it directly into your question and properly format it here. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], particularly [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "inline" video player. You are basically not setting the correct frame for your AVPayerViewController. This is not a question to be answered here since it's asking for a new tutorial on "how-to". Check the guides provided above by @KenWhite and ask specifically for a problem or something on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic